# Substitute values in a list at multiple indices

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the list:

```
mylist = [0] * 46
```

I want to set `mylist[i] = 1`, for each index in the list

```
indices_list = [0, 30, 40, 41]
```

Right now, I'm using a simple and readable `for` loop, since in Python you cannot use a list of indices as indices in a list (i.e., `mylist[indices_list] = 1` is not valid Python code):

```
for i in indices_list:
    mylist[i] = 1
```

and it works nicely. However, I've been told that it would be better to use a list comprehension. Is this true? If so, how would I do it, and what would be the advantage with respect to my simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nah, it is not better. A list comprehension **always** creates a new list object. That means it has to process every element of the 46! A simple loop over the list of only 4 indices is just fine!

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is absolutely fine, but if you are looking for a list-comprehension solution, following will work (*but less efficient than what you already have*):

```py
>>> [1 if i in indices_list else v for i,v in enumerate(mylist)]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lots of resources](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-replace-a-list-element-at-a-specific-index-in-python/) around this problem point in the direction that "*at the end of the day, a loop is fine*". I don't *like* solutions which try to import and leverage libraries (i.e. `numpy`, `pandas`), given that creating those objects comes with a cost. If you are already dealing with those objects, it is a natural thing to do obviously, but if you need to create one just to leverage a specific method and avoid a simple loop, maybe it is not always worth it.